# Android:No source path

Tags: android

Im having a pretty simple requirement.I have a Login activity. Once user enters login details and clicks on submit button, the application should perform a internet access check. If device is not connected to internet then it should display a toast saying "No internet access". If internet is accessible then the application will perform authentication and navigate to Home page.

I have written the code snippet to perform internet check in a separate class for re usability. The code snippet is as below:

```
package com.example.rinventory.Common;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;

public class ConnectionDetector 
{
  private Context _context; 
  public ConnectionDetector(Context context)
  {
    this._context = context;
  }

  public boolean isConnectingToInternet()
  {  
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    //Get all the active networks available. 
    NetworkInfo info = connectivity.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    //If it is connected to available networks return true else false.
    if(info != null && info.isConnected())
        return true;
    else
        return false;
  }
}
```

And my Login activity's submit button functionality is as below:

```
public class RInventoryLogin extends ActionBarActivity 
{
  boolean isInternetPresent = false;
  ConnectionDetector detect;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rinventory_login);

    Button btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
          //Throws error at this particular line
          isInternetPresent = detect.isConnectingToInternet();  

          if(isInternetPresent)
          {
            EditText editEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editEmail);
            EditText editPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editPassword);
            LoginData data = new LoginData();

            data.setEmail(editEmail.getText().toString());
            data.setPassword(editPassword.getText().toString());

            new CallJsonParserLogin().execute(data);
          }
          else
          {
            Toast.makeText(RInventoryLogin.this, "No Internet Access", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
        }
    });
  }
}
```

When I try to execute, it loads the activity. However once I enter login details and click on submit the application shuts down with "unexpectedly your application has stopped working"

I have included Internet, Network state parameters in Manifest file.

When I comment the line

> isInternetPresent = detect.isConnectingToInternet();

and subsequent if else blocks it just works fine. What might be the issue I'm missing here?

I have tried the same creating a demo application and that works fine.

Please help

Comment: The stack trace will say exactly what the error is and which line of code caused it.  Please edit your question and include it.

Comment: You mean the log cat detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not initializing `detect` object.

add this line before setting click listener to your button :

```
detect = new ConnectionDetector(this);
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, that solved it right. But out of curiousity I had not initialized the detect Object in another demo application and it just worked fine. I have no idea why?

Comment: please accept my answer if it solved your problem :)

post that code and I'll take a look at that for you

Comment: I accepted your answer, it allows user to accept answers only after a certain minutes of time...sorry for the delay, thanks again :)

Comment: your welcome! oh my bad! I'm not very experienced in SO. sorry :)